# Loopback: nested relations, get parent in query

Tags: api, loopback

so I have this scenario

models:
- competition
- competition-season
- match

where competition-season has:

```
  "relations": {
    "matches": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "match",
      "foreignKey": "competition-seasonId"
    },
    "competition": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "competition",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
```

and match has:

```
"relations": {
    "competition-season": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "competition-season",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get the competition object when listing the matches, but with this

```
{
  include: ['competition-season']
}
```

right now I am getting just

```
[
  {
    id: 'xxxx',
    competition-seasonId: 'yyyy',
    competition-season: {
      competitionId: 'zzzz'
    }
  }
]
```

So would like to get the competition object, not just the id

Answer (score 1):

I fiugured it out myself!

```
include: [
  {
    relation: 'competition-season',
    scope: {
      include: 'competition'
    }
  }
]
```

example here: [enter link description here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html)

**oughta love loopback**